# Search Input Control Should Retain Search String

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

The text input control (top right) should retain its value when used. Thus making it much easier to modify the search.

Currently one has to completely re-enter (with all typo likelihood), or navigate back (thus losing the initial results as reference.

EDIT: JUst tried again on SF. Search for "[windows]" consistently left a blank search box... some other searches left it populated and some didn't. There seems to be a lack on consistency. (All in FF.)

EDIT #2: As noted in the [answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22794) if the search consists of just tags, then it is treated as selecting those tags. This should still leave the search box populated to allow refinement of the search (i.e. keep the page content consistent with a search).

Comment: Up vote http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag for this feature request

Comment: This is completed, you can find details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag/78890#78890

Answer (score 4):

The reason a search for `[windows]` will not keep the term in the search box is because that will actually take you to the tag page.

Comment: This is what I (finally) realised. But I think this should not clear the search box as it makes refinement of the search harder.

Answer (score 3):

Which browser are you using? I currently observe the behaviour that you request to be implemented.

I just searched with the keyword *test*, and on the page which shows the search results there is the text *test* in the search textfield.

Comment: Aye, me too. I used a three part phrase and just built it out to test on Chrome Beta/Win7. Coincidentally, I discovered that the search for `rock em sock em robots` returns around 500 posts. See for yourself! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rock+em+sock+em+robots

Comment: And now it seems to be working (FF and IE)... but I *know* it wasn't earlier (and the first try with IE didn't work either).