# Fill search window with clicked tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When a tag page is viewed, populate the search box with that tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag)

When I click tag, I will likely limit my further search to this tag. Please fill search text box with "[tag]" text after clicking "tag".