# Remember last search terms during tag-only search to allow for refinement

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

When I do a tag-only search on the site (e.g. [rails]), the search results page doesn't remember that on the results page. It would be nice if it did - that would allow me to add to the search criteria without having the re-enter the tags from scratch.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag

Comment: Tag redirects (or directly visiting a tag page) will now populate the search box with the appropriate tag(s).

Answer (score 1):

We can't repro this.

I enter ...

`+apples +oranges`

... in the search box at the upper right, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search.

On the results page, the search box is now pre-filled with ...

`+apples +oranges`

Comment: Sorry, I realized that the problem occurs when searching on tags only, not general searches.

Comment: This is happening if you are searching on tags like `[soa]` or if the search key is transformed to a tag-search when you just type `soa`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a feature request or a bug report. When you enter a text search term (in combination with a tag or not), the box state is retained. When only tags are searched (which goes to a tagged/xyz page), the box state is not retained.

However, if you only search

Comment: @Jon It looks like an implementation, but not a bug. [tag] searches go to /questions/tagged/, while compound ones are /search?q=. To wit, you can duplicate tag searches without using the search bar, which is probably why it doesn't bother to update the search bar.

Comment: @jon that only applies to tags with top (n) status, however.