# Searched tag text is being cleared making refining searches annoying

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

I find that I always find my self doing a search on stack overflow on a specific tag and then refining that search by adding keywords to it

The problem is that the search bar gets cleared after the first search and I am forced to select the tag name and copy paste  or  retype it.

Would it be possible to keep the name in the search bar when you have just searched for it?

(e.g if I search [php] just keep that on there so I can continue without breaking my train of thought)

I wouldn't mind but it just keeps coming up

Comment: It *is* usually kept there, unless you explicitly searched for tags only. (at least for me, using FF3.6)

Comment: Sorry you're right let me refine the case

Comment: possible duplicate of [When a tag page is viewed, populate the search box with that tag.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Simple single-word searches for popular tags are auto-remapped into `/questions/tagged/{foo}` (as if you had clicked on the tag itself).

This is by design.

Comment: Looks like I have not been clear when I asked the question. I have edited my post to be more clear.    If the answer is still "this is by design" that is not great as I keep finding myself having to repeat the same redundant action when searching the site. I just typed it in and then its gone and I have to actively think about what needs to go back there before continuing

Comment: That looks more nagative than it really is. Love the site :-)