# Why does my user number show up in the search box when clicking my profile information?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, profile-page

Hey all-

I just noticed that if you click on your username on the top bar, when your profile shows up, in the search bar at the top you'll find an explicit search for your user account.  For my meta account, for example, I see `user:157031` whenever I click on my profile.

Is this deliberate?  If so, can I suggest removing that text?  It means that I have to manually delete the contents of the search field if I want to do a search from my profile screen.

Thanks!

Comment: But how often does that happen in real life? I tend to think it's a nice feature that helps search newbies understand how searching for own contributions works

Comment: Hmm... If I go to *your* profile page, the search box is populated with *your* user account number. Anyhow, I suspect this is by design. Interesting bugfeature.

Comment: It's by design, related to [this similar change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag/78890#78890), but I can't track down a reference at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design -- it indicates that when you are on the user page of a given user, you can scope your searches to just that user.