# How can I follow only questions with both [tag A] + [tag B] simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, subscription

How can I follow "tag A + tag B" simultaneously?
For instance:

- [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) + [python](/questions/tagged/python) (all questions that include **windows AND python**);
- [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) + [mono](/questions/tagged/mono) (all questions that include **linux AND mono**);
- [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) + [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) (all questions that include **asp.net AND solr**) and so on.

Comment: Do you mean "Subscribe for email notifications"?

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/filtering-questions-by-specifying-multiple-tags

Answer (score 2):

Im not 100% sure what you mean by "follow".  You can choose some favorite tags, and any post containing those tags will have a yellow background ([here is an explanation of all the colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)).

[image]

Alternatively you can simply search the site for questions containing those tags using the search bar at the top right corner of any screen on Stack Overflow -

[image]

The search query for tags is simply the tag name surrounded by square brackets.

Example -

To search for [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) use this - `[php][javascript]`

---

If you are referring to subscribing to tags - whereby you receive emails containing recent posts containing those tags, then I do not believe that you can subscribe to multiple tags simultaneously... You can subscribe to both and then perhaps utilize the tag filters on https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: `[php][javascript]` will follow questions with both tags (using AND), it there a way to follow either (ie using OR)?

Comment: @lev - sure you can! `[tag1] [or] [tag2]` -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87802/172936

Comment: odd .. I am sure I had tried this before, but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @lev - beware though - [a little bird told me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115678/tag-searches-with-or-or-wildcards-are-forgetful/115744#comment302295_115744) that this is not a supported feature...

Comment: Ah .. thanks, good to know, plus the link touches on why the search parameters entered in the box don't stick around, something I was wondering since it works with single tag searches.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Stack exchange does not provide a way for you to restrict subscription ("following") emails to questions that have specific tag combinations.  You may want to make a feature request for that, since it seems like a handy feature. (I'd use it myself if I didn't lurk in low-traffic tags.)

Reference:

1. [Your email subscriptions page](https://stackexchange.com/users/94276/paulo-cassiano?tab=subscriptions).
2. [The new-filter creation page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new).

**Workarounds:**

- Use Google Alerts.  For example:

  1. Go to [the Google-Alert creation page](http://www.google.com/alerts?hl=en).
  2. Enter a query like:
     `"Linux" "Mono" site:stackoverflow.com -site:meta.stackoverflow.com`
  3. Fill out the other fields to taste and create the alert.
  4. Confirm the email that Google sends.
- You could probably make something using [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).