# Info page about the [or] "tag" doesn't exist

Tags: bug

I'm lazy, and wanted to see if I could add [or] to my favorite tags so I wouldn't have to type  it in the search.  I know it's not an actual tag, but I was curious.

Searching for just [or] gives results, and shows "Questions tagged  or" under the question count.

Clicking the about » link takes you to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/or/info which doesn't exist.

Comment: I imagine these posts are related: [Tag searches with OR or wildcards are forgetful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115678/tag-searches-with-or-or-wildcards-are-forgetful/115744#115744), and [Search `[tag1]` OR `[tag2]`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2/87802#87802).  This is probably due to the "or" search parameter being parsed as a tag, even though it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is a bug, but the real problem is the [questions/tagged/or](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/or).

There is no  or  tag. The search takes `or` as a boolean search parameter and simply displays **all** MSO questions.

Comment: For a similar (I suppose) reason, `[meta-tag:or]` only works in the preview. Click [edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/139377/edit) to see what I mean.