# add 1 example to search-options page: Search [tag1] [OR] [tag2]

Tags: feature-request, search

Add another useful example-query to the [search-option](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page:

an explanation on how to combine searches for specific tags (OR'ing tags).

The whole thing is discussed here on MSO,

[Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

but the search-options page does *not* explain how to do this, but it should.  (Instead it explains much more complex and weirder queries)

Add one more line here:

> ```
> to specific tags
>
> [tag] apples oranges
> [tag] [another-tag] apples oranges
> ```
>
> **>     [tag] [OR] [another-tag] apples oranges**

...assuming the line is correct.. maybe you  cannot add any other search terms when you have used the [OR] operator with [tags]

Comment: The thing is, that `[tag1] [or] [tag2]` syntax [isn't supposed to work to begin with](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115678/tag-searches-with-or-or-wildcards-are-forgetful/115744#comment308979_115744). But I'm not sure how the in-progress changes to search impact the support for that functionality.

Comment: Recently I had to issue more complex tag-searches. I just encounted a situation where I have to combine [Screen-scraping] [OR] [web-scraping]. What I really want to do is `([Screen-scraping] [OR] [web-scraping]) AND [perl]`, and to this I'd like to add even more search terms.